# PHP GD Rezize (bigger or smaller)

Tags: php, image, gd

Here is my script

```
<?php
$user = $_GET['u'];
$src = imagecreatefrompng("http://www.website.com/".$user.".png");
$dest = imagecreatetruecolor(8, 8);
imagecopy($dest, $src, 0, 0, 8, 8, 80, 40);
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($dest);


imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
?>
```

Id like to so that the 8 by 8 image can be resized using GET.
Since its a 8 by 8 square and keeping the ratio, maybe something like s=20 so that it turns from 8x8 to 20x20.
The 8,8 in ImageCopy is a crop.

Comment: What is your question exactly? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I don't know how to resize an image that i am currently cropping without using a second file. but I dont want to resort to that.

Comment: Are you trying to resize from 8x8 to 20x20? That would be very bad-quality.

Comment: just an example. And its pixels, so id like it to be pixelated when resized.

Answer (score 1):

Try the Image_Transform package from PEAR. It can crop, resize, scale images and it's uses the GD lib.

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.images.image-transform.general.php

Comment: Cool library to know about. I had always done the PHP resizes with aspect manually in the past. Checking for max height, length, etc...